# Logistic regression with complete separation AND repeated measures

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures, sas, generalized-estimating-equations

Consider a typical logistic regression on data with a binary response $Y$, and some predictor variables $X$'s.

I understand that when the event is rare, or in the case of complete separation, one could apply the Firth correction, for example in SAS:

```
proc logistic data=mydata descending;
class x1;
model y=x1 / firth;
run;
```

Recently I encountered a situation where repeated measures were made for all subjects ($\text{time}=1,2,3)$. All $X$'s such as race and gender would be considered time-invariant. Only the binary response $Y$ might change over time.

With three rows per participant, I can then fix a mixed model or GEE (with repeated statements in SAS) to account for the repeated measures.

But what can I do in case of a rare event or complete separation now with repeated measures? After some research, it seems that the Firth correction is only available in `proc logistic`, which I believe does not handle repeated measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases I would personally go with a Bayesian model and an informative prior on the $\beta$'s. Using R, such model could look like this:

```r
library(brms)

# Specify an informative prior to handle separation
prior_info <- c(
  set_prior("normal(0, 1.5)", class = "b", coef = "predictor")
)

# Specify the model using brm
model <- brm(outcome ~ predictor + (1 | subject_id), 
             data = mydata,
             family = bernoulli(),
             prior = prior_info
)
# Plot conditional effects
conditional_effects(model)
```

There's lots of information on priors for logistic regressions. This gets you started: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/default-priors-for-logistic-regression-coefficients-in-brms/13742

If you go this route you might need to adjust the prior to make it work on your specific example.

Alternatively, it seems that `PROC NLMIXED` seems to be able to implement a "[Penalized Likelihood Logistic Regression for Sparse Data Using Data Priors](https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse-us/2020/as/AS14.pdf)".

Or this one from the same author: https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse-us/2020/as/AS14_ppt.pdf

I don't know enough about PROC NLMIXED to further commment on this though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative answer. I was pretty surprised that I could not find R or SAS documentation that deals with BOTH complete separation and repeated measures. I found a similar question asked 8 years ago: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178754/using-conditional-logistic-regression-for-repeated-measures-complete-separation

Comment: @RonaldCarlos happy you found it useful!