# Binary logistic regression: p-value of predictor containing all cases of response=1

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, binary-data

I'm analyzing a dataset with a set of binary predictors and a binary response variable using logistic regression.

The response variable equals 1 only if some variable $x=1$, so there is a clear link between these variables. However, both in models with single or multiple predictors, the coefficient of that variable is not significant (has high standard error).

Minimal reproducible example in R:

```
data<- data.frame(x=c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10)), y=c(rep(0,12),rep(1,8)))
model<- glm(y~x,data=data,family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model)
```

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -20.57    1773.04  -0.012    0.991
x              21.95    1773.04   0.012    0.990
```

Is logistic regression inappropriate for such data?
Models with this predictor explain the most variance, but reporting results with the coefficient of the most important predictor that is non-significant seems incorrect. Is there a proper way to indicate a link between such variables?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a read through this on methods for dealing with this:  https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/#:~:text=If%20it%20is%20quasi%2Dcomplete,predicts%20the%20outcome%20variable%20effectively.

Comment: Maybe this one helps too: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/639550/32477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple notes first regarding your questions:

> Is logistic regression inappropriate for such data?

In theory, yes.

> Models with this predictor explain the most variance, but reporting
> results with the coefficient of the most important predictor that is
> non-significant seems incorrect.

This is not true. You should always report the results of your pre-specified model because it is a true test of your hypothesis rather than an attempt at a fishing expedition for $p$ values.

On to your major problem here. It looks like your data has a case of [quasi-complete separation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2772766123000046#:%7E:text=This%20occurs%20due%20to%20a,quasi%2Dcomplete%20separation%20which%20occurs). Inspecting the data directly shows us this:

```
> data
   x y
1  0 0
2  0 0
3  0 0
4  0 0
5  0 0
6  0 0
7  0 0
8  0 0
9  0 0
10 0 0
11 1 0
12 1 0
13 1 1
14 1 1
15 1 1
16 1 1
17 1 1
18 1 1
19 1 1
20 1 1
```

Which shows that only two cases are not the same as the others. The model is consequently unreliable and should be abandoned. Some possible options are [discussed here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/#:%7E:text=If%20it%20is%20quasi%2Dcomplete,predicts%20the%20outcome%20variable%20effectively.) and the linked article above. Probably your best bet is a penalized model or a Bayes model with very precise priors, but that won't guarantee a good model, only the chance of one.

Comment: Very precise priors are not needed! All you need is a normal prior with mean = 0 and standard deviation of 2 applied on the logit scale. A prior like this is not very informative. It only prevents the sampler from spending too much time exploring the areas close to +/- infinity.